# Ajax call works on localhost but on live site returns 'Call to a member function prepare() on null' in the error log

Tags: php, ajax

My Ajax call I have is to post to the db and manipulate the page without causing it to refresh. The following is a working example on my local version however on the live site it throws a POST 500 error, and after checking the error logs it displays a 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null' message.

ajax.php

```
require_once '../Database.php';
$db = new Database;

$db->query('INSERT INTO post (values) VALUES(:values)');
```

Database.php

```
    class Database {
      // define private $host, $user, $pass, $dbname

      private $dbh;
      private $stmt;
      private $error;
    
      public function __construct(){
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
    
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
      }
    
      public function query($sql){
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the db connection failed. Did you change the login user/pass and maybe the host as well, to match the new LIVE environmant

Comment: Your connection failed, so `$this->dbh` is null. You'll need to check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to find out why.

Comment: You need also to bind variables to the statement or pass an array `$stmt->execute(array(':var' => $value))` etc - currently the above code does not actually execute the cmd. The DSN you construct does not have a password supplied

Comment: Where and how are `$this->dbname` and `$this->host` defined?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius the db name and host are constants created in config, here in the Database class they are assigned to the private variables $dbname and $host respectively

Comment: @aynber okay, I will look for PDO errors and see what is being returned, thank you

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I have altered the relevant db values for my live environment, all other features site-wide are running normally, it's just this one ajax call